# Subtraces of delegatecall in Parity trace

Tags: solidity, parity, delegatecall

I'm investigating transactions using [Parity trace](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-trace-module) which provides useful data over a transaction flow. Among this data is the `Subtraces` field which allows me to understand how many sub-calls each action has.

When delegate-call is used it seems that the subtraces are a bit confusing.
For example, looking at [this transaction trace](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x100b6398910f70f564ad1bd6963adce9a32e1de0c749d16eaa5d53fd83c5b435&type=parity#decoded) I can see a few delegate calls, for example `Action [6]` which has 1 subtrace, but I can't see any action called by this step (by `0x2157a7894439191e520825fe9399ab8655e0f708` in this case).
Why is that? What is the meaning of the subtraces field in calls of type delegatecall?

Comment: Did you find a answer for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: nope.. :( 
 I guess it relates to the the special characteristics of calls of type delegate-call.